# Resident front instance keeps shutting down from time to time

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have 1 resident F4 and I ping my app every 10 seconds on various places because I have low traffic. I have a 15 sec pending latency.  Like that my users almost all the time avoid cold starts and the latencies between RPCs are not too high either. Except from time to time, more or less every 1 or 2 hours cause all my front instances shut down, including the resident one before restarting.

There is no errors in the logs so I don't understand why the resident instance shut down. Does anyone knows something about resident instances shutting down by themselves every one or two hours?

Comment: do you have billing enabled?

Answer (score 1):

F4 is too much for a low traffic app. Also stop pinging your app as all you are doing is incurring in more costs.

Resident instances do not shutdown, unless manually forced to. From GAE Console:

> Idle Instances are pre-loaded with your application code, so when a
>   new Instance is needed, it can serve traffic immediately

What that means is that **resident instances** start serving your pages to avoid high latency, it's not that they shutdown. They start serving pages, if they become too busy they become dynamic and another resident instance is started in its place. For that reason you will sometimes see the age of a resident instance younger than their dynamic counterparts.